# Using basic arrays for compatibility

Tags: c++, arrays

Imagine a function from a library that takes an array as argument, in their own code, the users may use various array implementations, some will use std::vectors, some will use std::array, some will use basic arrays, some may even create their own classes, we can't satify every user. But every type of array works with a pointer and a size (stored somewhere or not, but known), could using a pointer and a size (if needed) as arguments solve this problem ?

Comment: `some will use std::vectors, some will use std::array, some will use basic arrays,` aaand that's why we have [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) and all [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) work on iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could using a pointer and a size (if needed) as arguments solve this problem ?

Yes. That's typical C-ish api used since forever, like string functions with bounds checking or `mem*` functions like `memcpy` or `memcmp` functions or [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) takes a pointer and count of elements etc.

But C++ saw that not every "array" has to be an array really, so C++ uses [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) to abstractly pass the information of something that you can "iterate" on. Every `std::vectors` and `std::array` and "basic arrays" all have their own iterators and all [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) are abstractly written with iterators in mind. Because iterators are overloaded with custom operators, you can do almost anything, like ex. [inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) allows for putting elements into a vector as they come.

There is also the recent addition of [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges). Ranges invert the syntax of iterators like inside out and offer simpler and safer use and amazing and simple functionality.

Comment: does it means if i were to create my onw array, I should implement iterators and algorithms for it so I can pass it to any function from a library that doesn't know my own array ?

Comment: It is preferred to provide an iterator for your own types, as then you may use existing algorithms from existing libraries with your own type. And you implement new algorithms when if the ones from standard library are not enough for you. It's fun to do `CustomArray arr; std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); for (auto&& v : arr) [}` and don't care what is `CustomArray`.

Comment: I only knew C for 2 years, the C++ way is much much better. Except for performance, all those function calls must slow the program a lot.

Comment: `all those function calls must slow the program a lot` In usuall situations, there are no function calls, because everything is inlined, because it's all templated. In some cases C++ is way faster, because there are no function calls in C++, like ex. `std::sort` vs `qsort`.

Comment: Why does the fact that it is templated implies that it is inlined ? Why can't the STL have functions compiled at compile time ?

Comment: `Why does the fact that it is templated implies that it is inlined ?` If the compiler does inline a function is up to the compiler. It doesn't _imply_ that, but it _allows_ the compiler to do the inlining if he wants to (without using any advanced things, like LTO). `Why can't the STL have functions compiled at compile time ?` makes no sense - everything is compiled at compile time, C++ is not a scripting language.